# how can i translate nested objects in nextjs with next translation

Tags: next.js, localization, internationalization, react-i18next

i have the following data and i have to pass it as object which contains arrays also

```
const data = {
        title: " Asked Questions",
        rows: [
            {
                title: "What is AISEO360?",
                content:
                    "Fitbunny is revolutionary and we are different. A project with it's people in mind, equipping its community with habits, skills, and discipline to give that extra competitive advantage in good health.",
            },
            {
                title: "Which languages does AISEO360 support?",
                content:
                    "First, we identify their challenges and goals (Eg- Depression,Body Transformation, Better pay cheque, Mental Health, Muscle Gain, etc)",
            },
            {
                title: "Do I have to sign a long-term contract?",
                content:
                    "Curabitur laoreet, mauris vel blandit fringilla, leo elit rhoncus nunc",
            },
            {
                title: "Does AISEO360 provide an AI Image Generator?",
                content:
                    "We have created 4444 access passes and a unique collection of 10,000 artworks on the Polygon blockchain. Fitbunny artworks have been uniquely designed with unique graphics, giving it a high rarity score that can be seen in low amounts in the market. Each artwork is different from the others.4444 of 10000 artworks will be airdropped to access pass holders and the remaining sold in open market.",
            },

            {
                title: "Did AISEO360 build a ChatGPT tool?",
                content:
                    "Way 1. Reach Level 10 Be an active member of the community by positively engaging in our channels. Meaningful conversations only, spamming will not be tolerated. You can check your current level in our level channel.",
            },
            {
                title:
                    "Is Chatsonic by aiseo360 the ultimate ChatGPT alternative??            ",
                content:
                    "By connecting your wallet to our website and verifying that you are a Fitbunny holder, you can stake your NFTs and claim rewards daily. The NFT will be locked as long as you want to stake. You will need to complete one whole cycle to receive the $HERB Tokens.",
            },
        ],
    };
```

so how can i get these translations and then pass them to component

so far i was doing this

```
const title = t('data.title');
    const rows = t('data.rows', { returnObjects: true });
 const da = {
        title: t('data.title'),
        rows: t('common:.', { returnObjects: true })
    };
    console.log("dara", da);
```

the data in my locale files is like this

```
 "data": {
        "title": " Asked Questions",
        "rows": [
            {
                "title": "What is AISEO360?",
                "content": "Fitbunny is revolutionary and we are different. A project with it's people in mind, equipping its community with habits, skills, and discipline to give that extra competitive advantage in good health."
            }
        ]
    }
```

as a result i was only getting the value of title at start and it was not returning the value of rows